# Remoting into Windows 7 computer wipes out PATH

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, path

When I remote into my Windows 7 computer (local admin user), weird things are happening.

I had RDC (mstsc) and Windows Explorer icon on my Task Bar, clicked on them then "cannot find item" error, Visual Studio 2010-2013 wouldn't open with an "Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation" dialog. all went haywire. Wasn't able to run my Python scripts from the command line unless I go to the python directory. Ah, a clue...

Fired up cmd, typed path... (null).  What?!

Remotely rebooted my computer, waited for it to come back up before logging in again, all is fine.

Happens all the time.  Any ideas?

One idea is that my user profile is corrupted and I should just wipe it out.  Want to be sure that is the case before I engage in this effort.

Comment: I do not use user profiles, but to test couldnt you setup yet another user , run the same or similar operations for some time , and see if it fails similar, prior to wiping out a profile that may not be the problem?  Speaking of time, is there a pattern to the time?  Specific to computer activity? or even lack of activity (something sleeping)?

Comment: Used another profile, works fine.  That's why I suspect it's a bad or corrupted user profile. *sigh* I'll just wipe it out, start again, and report back if it still persists.  Thanks for the response @Psycogeek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your path is probably longer than 2048.  That is a published limit, and reducing your path below that will probably solve your problem.
I'm not sure why RDP triggers it.  My path is over 2048 when I first boot up, and it doesn't seem to matter... until I access the my workstation remotely using RDP.

Comment: That would make sense, my path is usually crazy long.